# How I can used the following information to put it in a textView(Android), using retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

[Here is JSON with the following property what I want to be set in textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qck7v.jpg)

Comment: Please attempt that on your own and post a question if you experience any problems or get any errors. I am sure this is important to you, so give it a try first before posting here for people to do it for you.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a bad formatted question. Very vague. Let me try and answer it as best as possible with many assumptions since you provided very little context.

- First, let's assume you have your `json` in a String variable called
  `json`.
- Second, let's assume that you've correctly initialized your
  textView and have it in a variable called `textView`.

The code for achieving this would be:

```
JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject("Project");
int id = obj.getInt("ID");
textView.setText(String.ValueOf(id)); //or simply textView.setText("" + id);
```